# SQLError in JDBC, but works fine in Oracle SQLDeveloper

Tags: oracle, jdbc

It's been a while since I've been using JDBC, so I'm having a hard time to figure out why the following statement works in SQLDeveloper but not as a PreparedStatement in JDBC.

```
select ko.id AS KOSTKALKID, 
au.auftragsnummer AS AUFTRAGSNUMMER, 
to_char(au.datesap,'DD.MM.YYYY') AS Bausoft_an_TS, 
fe.wert, to_char(fe.datesap,'DD.MM.YYYY') AS TS_Fertiggemeldet, 
to_char(fe.datum,'DD.MM.YYYY') AS TS_Fertigmeldung_Datum, 
bem.name AS TS_Montagemeister, 
to_char(au.tech_baueinweisung,'DD.MM.YYYY') AS TS_Baueinweisung, 
to_char(au.tech_baubeginn,'DD.MM.YYYY') AS TS_Baubeginn, 
to_char(au.tech_baufertig,'DD.MM.YYYY') AS TS_Bauende
from kostenkalkulation ko
inner join auftrag au on au.KOSTENKALKULATIONID=ko.id
left outer join fertigmeldung fe on au.auftragsnummer=fe.auftragsnummer
left outer join benutzer bem on bem.id=au.montagemeisterid
where au.auftragsnummer like '849%' or au.auftragsnummer like '848%' or au.auftragsnummer like '847%';
```

executing the PreparedStatemenmt leads me to the following error

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

I understand that there are countless similar threads here on stackoverflow but none of them were helpful in my case

So, any advise would be appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: remove the `;` at the end of your command

Comment: That special moment when a simple semicolon cost you 2 hours of precious lifetime. Thanks a lot. That helped.

Comment: My SQLs are stored in a textfile accessed by using a ResourceStream. But the problem's already solved. Thanks a lot though

Comment: Always happy to help a fellow countryman ;-)